# How to extract all the source code under <table> and export as html?

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I am beginner of Scrapy. My goal is to **extract selected tables from a big HTML page and then export the selected tables together in HTML format**. So essentially, what I want is to **get a shorter version of the original web page keeping only the `<table>` sections**.

The structure of each `<table>` section looks like this:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> 
          <font>
```

Currently, I am trying the following spider code but the **problem** is:

1. it doesn't retain all the source formatting;
2. the `<table>` and `</table>` are not included;
3. I don't know how to save the scraped results in html format.

---

```
  def parse(self, response):
      hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
      titles = hxs.select("//document/type/sequence/filename/description/text/table")
      items = []
      for titles in titles:
          item = MyHtmlItem()
          item ["htmltext"] = titles.select("node()").extract()
          if (item["htmltext"]):
              items.append(item)
      return items
```

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: What portion of code is it saved ? Can you share your output logs ?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Currently, the output file is in csv format where there is one column. The html code within each `<table>` element is saved separately into each cell.

Comment: Since the output log is really long, I am displaying the scraped code of one of the many `<table>`s down below:

Comment: `,<tr>
<td width="3%"><font size="1">Â </font></td>
<td width="2%" valign="top" align="left"><font style="font-family:Times New Roman" size="2">Â•</font></td>
<td width="1%" valign="top"><font size="1">Â </font></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"> <p align="justify"><font style="font-family:Times New Roman" size="2">leave your camera at home because cameras, transmission, broadcasting and other recording devices, including certain smart phones, may not be
permitted in the meeting rooms; and </font></p></td></tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and you need to extract only original tables html from page, then solution is very simple:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # XPath query to get all tables from response
    tables_selectors = response.xpath('//table')
    tables_html = tables_selectors.extract()
    ...
```

tables_html is array of strings from original tables html. Process it as you want.

Some recommendations:

Your syntax looks a little bit obsolete, it seems that you are using an outdated Scrapy manual.

Please check the latest documentation at [official site](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/)

When working with tables, be careful with tbody tag in your XPath queries.

Hope this helps!